# How to fetch data using ASP.NET web-service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, excel, export

Newbie to web-services, so asking few basic questions
I have a some data around 50 MB in MS Excel, I plan to host a web-service, to implement a simple functionality

1. user app will be populated with country name, city names (This info will be feched from webservice
2. on selecting country and city, user will be provided with city's details (ex. ranking, etc)

I plan to make web-service in ASP.NET ( reason for choosing ASP.NET: probably it is simple), so

> 1. Which data base to choose? only read operations to be done.also data base size will remain <50 MB
> 2. Can ms excel direcltly be used?
> 3. Do i need to export excel to some data base and then use that database to establish connectivity with ASP.NET web service?

Please share.

Comment: how about transferring data to mysql and using mysql db to access from the web-service?

Comment: Loading the data into any db backend will be infinitely better. You will have all the advantages built-in such a system: memory management, concurrency handling, record locking, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transfer data to mysql and using mysql db to access from the web-service.
This is the approach i finally used.

Answer (score 1):

If the total size of your data is less that 50 MB and it will never be updated, it would be best to load all that data into memory.

You can read the excel file directly using a Jet driver.
Load this into a static variable so that all requests can access it.

Keeping it in memory will give you very fast access, and you will not have to worry about querying the database(or excel file) everytime.

Comment: i wanted to keep excel seperate so that in any case i update my excel, i can eeasily export it to database.

Comment: 50Mb is a very small amount of data. Servers these days have GBs of memory. Once loaded, your excel file is not required. You can overwrite it as needed, and you can reload it in memory on those rare occasions too

Answer (score -1):

In a Web application, no matter how big it will be, memory management is the most important thing you should do. It's important because you don't actually know how many web requests the app should answer at the same time. By the way, it depends on how you keep the data on memory, it's shared or private. After all, when your application is asleep and there is no active requests, keeping 50 MB data on the memory is not nice. It's the reason why we have database engines such as Microsoft SQL Server or Oracle, cause they do all these things like a service.

In my point of view, it's better to keep data on disk. The way of storing data depends on the output result of the web service method. If it's XML, so you can simply store cities list on a XML file and transfer it to the output result every time it was requested. In this way, you can use Streaming on the web services to find out how you can return large data on a web service method.

Also using a excel file directly is not a good idea, because it might need some components on the web server and it will effect the deployment process. Usage of an excel file in .NET has some complexities instead of connecting to SQL, or reading a XML file. So I certainly do not recommend that.

Cheers

Comment: -1 for storing XML files on disk. File IO is _**very**_ expensive, not to mention file locks, etc. Holding 50 Mb in memory is negligible.

Comment: @ShaiCohen I know that it's expensive storing data on disk, as I said, you yourself go use an database engine! BUT storing 50 MB data per request (or not!) is not a right way to do this. You're escaping from the correct way. Everything should be made simple, not simpler! Cheers

Comment: But it is not "per request". It is a single 50Mb file that is used for all requests. That's why I am suggesting storing it in memory. If it _**was**_ 50Mb for each request, then I would definitely need my head examined :) Also, I would be very surprised if a 50Mb excel file translated to anywhere near that much memory once it is extracted from the file.

Comment: You know what, you are right, but I have a problem that you don't care about how much memory you're using. If everyone in a team think like you and every section stores about 50 MB memory for resulting some simple reports, then application should go fix its problem itself! and simply no body cares. You can have a 2 KB exe written in C++ that does many things. The problem is how much do you care about the quality of resource usage. It's like you give me 50 $, maybe some day I'd spend that for some reason that I don't know now. Would you?!

Comment: "you don't care about how much memory you're using" - I am horribly offended! :). But seriously, I think then we can agree? If it is only ~50Mb in memory for use across all session/requests it is permissible, but this is not the type of long-term architecture that is recommended. And, of course, if everyone on the team stores that much in memory without communication to the other members of the team, it is definitely a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Now I think we are talking! :D As I said, you are right, seriously. What I say is that in information systems, the storage should be targeted in database. It's better to import the data stored in file (no matter what type it is) into the database using DTS and make a model for it, then you can make a report out of the model. Also as while as you are using a database engine, all the memory management and disk usage things is done and there is no need to customize it in such a unstable memory like the memory of your web server.

Comment: Also sometimes web servers apply some limitation on your web application, specially in host providers. like this comment that has length limitation! ;) Cheers